# Measuring Angular Bootstrap Time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looking for an ideal way to hook into and measure the time of bootstrapping an angular application which uses 'automatic intialization' (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap).

I've looked around and there doesn't appear to be a good built-in hook where I could measure the start/end-time with.

Anyone know of a nice solution for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it only for testing performance you can use

```
console.time("Bootstrap");
//DO YOUR BOOTSTRAPPING
console.timeEnd("Bootstrap");
```

And then look at the console log in chrome

Comment: So, in angular.js, it's auto bootstrap call looks like:  ``jqLite(document).ready(function() {
    angularInit(document, bootstrap);
  });`` --- How would I wrap that statement without modifying angular.js library directly? (Note: I'm not manually bootstrapping my application. Let me know if that doesn't make sense).

Comment: You could put the first function in a `<script>` tag with a self calling function that fires at the start of the application and the second one in `angular.module("app", [dependencies]).run(function(){ //CALL IT HERE })`

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide an answer here: looking further into angular.boostrap, it appears you currently have to manually bootstrap and time both before and after. Alternatively, if you don't want to manually bootstrap angular, you'd have to edit/update angular to have a callback hook before/after.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using W3C User Timing. For example, if you isert a timing mark here, then wouldn't this show the entry point since  Angular begins to execute here. Then inserting another mark to calculate the time once you know the end. I used a JavaScript code I found that measures the Bootstrap finish.

performance.mark('entryPoint');
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)

window.performance && performance.measure && performance.measure("BootDuration", "entryPoint", "AngularBootstrapFinished");